# How can a .jmp file (from the statistical software JMP) be imported into Mathematica?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, import

The Wolfram documentation and MSE say nothing about the statistical software JMP or .jmp files. A simple `Import["filename.jmp"]` or `Import["filename"]` seems to interpret the file as an audio file. Does anyone know how to import a .jmp file into Mathematica?

Comment: If no direct import is available, how how doing in two steps?  JMP data table to Excel to *Mathematica*.  (I'm assuming it must be JMP data and not JMP programming commands.)

Comment: Thanks that works! It is surprising that Mathematica cannot import JMP data directly.

Comment: Does SAS publish the structure of a .jmp file?  A quick Google search didn't turn up anything.  And maybe there are licensing issues.  SAS might insist on very specific and prominent references:  https://www.sas.com/en_us/legal/editorial-guidelines.html.